# Routing WebApi through Point-to-Site and Site-to-site on Azure

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

i have a webAPI hosted on azure. It connects to 3rd party site using their dev env IPAddress and Port. This works fine. The requirement was to then create site-to-site VPN connection to connect to their live env.

I created a VNet,vNetGateway and localGateway. the VnetGateway using a new public IP that connects successfully to their localGateway.

Then i want to route my webAPI through the vNetGateway so i setup the point-to-site configuration.

My webAPI is making a socket connection internally pointed at their subnet address and port they specified but all i can see is conn errors.

What is the web address and port the webApi should be connecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable BGP on the site-to-site connection. Without BGP, the P2S client (webapp) will not get the routes to remote site. You will have to create the P2S configuration again after you enable BGP on the S2S connection for it to work.